# How to get only the "make" and "model" data from this json output in either java or jquery. Java isp preferred

Tags: java, jquery

How to extract make and model from this json output.

```
[
  "{\"_id\":{\"$oid\":\"5a81d2136da3cd4c41b21509\"},\"make\":\"maruti\",\"model\":\"astar\",\"year\":1998}"
]
```

Comment: Did you tried ? Reading a JSON in java/JQuery is well documented so you should be able to find the answer in no time... you don't seems to have search at all unfortunatly

Answer (score 1):

Use JSON.parse to convert string to the JS object and then access the properties using dot notation.

You don't even need jQuery for this. Following is an example:

```js
let data = [
  "{\"_id\":{\"$oid\":\"5a81d2136da3cd4c41b21509\"},\"make\":\"maruti\",\"model\":\"astar\",\"year\":1998}"
];

data[0] = JSON.parse(data[0]);
console.log(data[0].make, data[0].model);
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mentioned, it was a dynamic query genration and we dont know about the key and value

Answer (score 0):

To extract JSON data in jQuery you can do following.

```
var d = $.parseJSON(data);
var make = data.make;
var model = data.model;
```

in make and model you will get your desired output. 
Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mentioned, it was a dynamic query genration and we dont know about the key and value, every time, key and value value will be different.